# how to save a model that has existing data as well as new data?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I currently have a model that has existing data as well as new data.

As an example this is my model

```
 public class NameDetails
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

This is the mock data that it currently has

```
  List<NameDetails> Names = new List<NameDetails>{

                new  NameDetails{Id = 1, Name = "Name 1"},
                new NameDetails{Id = 2 , Name = "Name 2"},
            };
```

Now suppose I need to save this onto a database.. I already have the id = 1 in the table, so that should be an update where as the id = 2 should be an add... how can I do that?

Previously when I have written saves using a repository I did either an add or an edit
Add like so,

```
 context.NameDetails.Add(NameDetails); 
    context.SaveChanges();
```

or 
Edit like so,

```
var recordToUpdate = context.NameDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id== 1);
recordToUpdate.Name = "New name";
context.SaveChanges();
```

so does that mean I have to loop through my list and work out what is new and what isn't.. or is there another way?

Comment: You only have 2 options: - Query the database to figure out if the object already exists. Or - Have the object hold some property to determine if it is new (eg. Id=0)

Comment: Not sure if it is truly relevant, but where are you getting the Id value of 2 from for the new record?

Comment: @user2266486 Or make a stored procedure that performs an upsert, but I'm wondering if there isn't more to this question/problem

Answer (score 2):

You could use some conventions that work fine with Entity Framework.

For instance, if you use `IDENTITY(1,1)` on your database (so it generates IDs for your inserted rows automatically), your entity property should use [`StoreGeneratedPattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.storegeneratedpattern.aspx) set as `Identity` (case of Model first approach), and your `Id` property with a `0` value means **it is not yet added into the database**.

Then you could easily decide what's to add and what's to update. Here's some pseudo (untested) code:

```
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    if (entity.Id == 0)
    {
        // Adds to the context for a DB insert
        context.Entities.Add(entity);
    }
    else
    {
        // Updates existing entity (property by property in this example, you could update
        // all properties in a single shot if you want)
        var dbEntity = context.Entities.Single(z => z.Id == entity.Id);
        dbEntity.Prop1 = entity.Prop1;
        // etc...
    }
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

**EF5+ only:**

If you have a way to detect whether or not an item is new (Id == 0 is good, as in ken2k's answer) you can do this to avoid needing to map things:

```
foreach(var entity in entities)
{
    context.NameDetails.Attach(entity);
    context.Entry(entity).State = IsNewEntity(entity) 
                                  ? EntityState.Added
                                  : EntityState.Modified;
}
```

This will tell EntityFramework to create INSERTs for the new entities and UPDATEs for the old entities.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var nameIds = Names.Select(n => n.Id);

var recordsToUpdate = context.NameDetails.Where(x => nameIds.Contains(x.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework doesn't perform very well in these kind of situations. This should get you close to what you are looking for:

```
public class NameDetails
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

List<NameDetails> Names = new List<NameDetails>
    {
        new  NameDetails{Id = 1, Name = "Name 1"},
        new NameDetails{Id = 2 , Name = "Name 2"},
    };


var toFetch = Names.Select(n => n.Id).ToArray();
var association = context.NameDetails
                         .Where(n => toFetch.Contains(n.Id))
                         .ToDictionary(n => n.Id);

foreach(var name in Names)
{
    NameDetails existing;
    if(association.TryGetValue(name.Id, out existing))
    {
        // It exists, map the properties in name to existing
    }
    else
    {
        // It's new, perform some logic and add it to the context
        context.NameDetails.Add(name);
    }
}

context.SaveChanges()
```

Alternatively, you could try to hijack Entity Framework Migration's [`AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) that performs an upsert:

```
// You need a namespace import of  System.Data.Entity.Migrations
context.NameDetails.AddOrUpdate(names.ToArray());
context.SaveChanges();
```

I haven't tried this, but it should work, unless there is an additional logic in the `AddOrUpdate` that eludes me.

Comment: I took a quick look at the implementation for AddOrUpdate and - although the way it builds the expressions is a bit mind-bending - to doesn't look like it's creating any magic upsert SQL. I'm pretty sure it makes a query to try to get the entity you pass in and updates the entity if it finds it or adds it if there is no such entity. That's nice when you're seeding a DB and everything is in memory already, maybe not so nice when you're unexpectedly issuing a whole bunch of TOP(1) queries to your DB.